# RegisterWaitForSingleObject Undeclared (First Use This Function)

Tags: c++, boost-asio, dev-c++

Okay, I have spent the past week trying to find the solution to this on Google and searching multiple coding sites, including the following link:

http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/boost-asio-UnregisterWaitEx-RegisterWaitForSingleObject-has-not-been-declared-td4633963.html

This was how I knew to use

```
-D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -DWINVER=0x0601
```

In the compiling line.

I am using Windows 7 (64-bit) with Dev-C++ and I am getting the following errors any time I compile a Boost:Asio example:

```
Compiler: Default compiler
Building Makefile: "D:\Tutorials\Asio\Makefile.win"
Executing  make...
make.exe -f "D:\Tutorials\Asio\Makefile.win" all
g++.exe -c main.cpp -o main.o -I"D:/Programs/Dev-Cpp/lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/include"  -I"D:/Programs/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/backward"  -I"D:/Programs/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/mingw32"  -I"D:/Programs/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2"  -I"D:/Programs/Dev-Cpp/include"  -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -DWINVER=0x0601 -lboost_system-mgw44-mt-1_49  

In file included from D:/Programs/Dev-Cpp/include/boost/asio/detail/win_object_handle_service.hpp:180,
                 from D:/Programs/Dev-Cpp/include/boost/asio/windows/object_handle_service.hpp:24,
                 from D:/Programs/Dev-Cpp/include/boost/asio/windows/basic_object_handle.hpp:27,
                 from D:/Programs/Dev-Cpp/include/boost/asio.hpp:99,
                 from main.cpp:3:
D:/Programs/Dev-Cpp/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_object_handle_service.ipp: In member function `void boost::asio::detail::win_object_handle_service::register_wait_callback(boost::asio::detail::win_object_handle_service::implementation_type&, boost::asio::detail::scoped_lock<boost::asio::detail::win_mutex>&)':
D:/Programs/Dev-Cpp/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_object_handle_service.ipp:376: error: `RegisterWaitForSingleObject' undeclared (first use this function)
D:/Programs/Dev-Cpp/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_object_handle_service.ipp:376: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in.)

D:/Programs/Dev-Cpp/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_object_handle_service.ipp: In static member function `static void boost::asio::detail::win_object_handle_service::wait_callback(void*, BOOLEAN)':
D:/Programs/Dev-Cpp/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_object_handle_service.ipp:418: error: `RegisterWaitForSingleObject' undeclared (first use this function)

make.exe: *** [main.o] Error 1

Execution terminated
```

My code is as follows:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0601
#define __USE_W32_SOCKETS
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    // Cre'ation du service principal et du re'solveur.
    boost::asio::io_service ios;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(ios);   // (1)              

    // Parame`trage du resolver sur Developpez.com
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query("www.developpez.com", "80"); // (2)

    // On re'cupe`re une "liste" d'ite'rateur
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator iter = resolver.resolve(query); // (3)
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator end; //Marqueur de fin
    while (iter != end) // On ite`re le long des endpoints
    {
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint = *iter++;
        std::cout << endpoint << std::endl; // on affiche (4)
    }

    return 0;
 }
```

Considering there were no errors given for the code itself, that doesn't matter.  This is just one of five tutorials I have been working with that gives me the same, exact errors with Boost:Asio.

There have been suggestions given such as use "-lwsock32" in the linker and "-lboost_system-mgw44-mt-1_49" in the compiler as well, but that didn't do anything.  Adding the "-D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -DWINVER=0x0601" as suggested removed some errors but that is about as far as I have gotten.

I am very serious about implementing Boost:Asio into my program so if I could but get a working example, I could get a better understanding of it from various resources and use it as intended.  Thus, please, don't give me anything about "leave it to the professionals" or "learn to program" as I have seen time and time again on other forums of people asking for help on this very error.  Even though I know how to program, I still face errors like this when using a library with which I am unfamiliar.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
#include <windows.h>
```

to the top of your file, just after your `#define`s. It looks as if Boost is using a win32 function without itself including windows.h.

Comment: I tried that, like you said, but the errors I am getting are exactly the same. I tried placing that line in various places at the headers but the result was always the same.
`#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0601
#define __USE_W32_SOCKETS
#include <windows.h>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>`

Comment: Are you able to use the function at all? Try this little snippet: #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500

#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    RegisterWaitForSingleObject(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 10UL, 10UL);
}

Comment: Still getting a similar, albeit shorter, compiling error: 
`main.cpp: In function int main()':
main.cpp:29: error: RegisterWaitForSingleObject' undeclared (first use this function)
main.cpp:29: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in.)`